# How to add faces to a shapefile using pyshp?

Tags: python, shapefile

I am working on shapefiles, I am using the python library pyshp, 
I would like to add faces to my shapefile using a script,

Did anyone worked on a similiar case before ?

thank you for your response

Comment: What do you mean by "faces"?  Are they polygons, lines, points, tesselated surfaces?  Do you have any other attributes associated with them? (e.g. a name, etc)  Right now it's not clear what you're asking.  If you can include some additional information, you'll be more likely to get a helpful answer.

Comment: I would like to add polygons to salome ( a geometry and meshing platform) using the shapefile, I've managed to read them but I couldn't extract them.